# Converting byte[] of a PDF file original source to MemoryStream for loading into PDF viewer? (component one)

Tags: silverlight, file, pdf, stream

I'm working with a ComponentOne (C1) silverlight PDF viewer control.
It has a "LoadDocument" method that accepts a "Stream".

I'm making an HTTP get call from my client app to get a PDF document.
This document, on the server side, has been streamed in through File.ReadAllBytes(), then converted to a base64 string using Convert.ToBase64String().
This string is sent across the wire back to my silverlight app where it's then reversely converted back into a byte array with Convert.FromBase64String(val).
Then I'm creating a MemoryStream with that byte array and passing "LoadDocument()" that memory stream.

The viewer is rendering nothing. It shows the toolbar and scrollbars, but the contents are blank and the save button is grayed out, suggesting that no document loaded.
I know for certain the file made it across because the byte array size on the client matches teh byte array pre-conversion on the server side.

Here's my code: (in the interest of time/space, i've truncated, removing validation, etc.)

*SERVERSIDE*

```
string sendingToClient = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath))
```

*CLIENTSIDE*

```
byte[] image = null;
image = Convert.FromBase64String(stringFromServerCall);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image);
docViewer.LoadDocument(stream);
```

*edit* As a potential workaround, I attempted to save the file into isolated storage with a ".pdf" extension. Then I use the IsolatedStorageFileStream to send to LoadDocument().
I've come to an actual error, it now says "PdfParserException was unhandled by user code: invalid file format (missing pdf header)"

Can anyone shed some light on this PDF header?

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding it? That just bloats the download size but I can't see any benefit to it.

Comment: existing code logic. reluctant to change for fear of breaking existing deployed applications that use this API layer. although i could create an entirely new API entry point.

Comment: Create a new one and deprecate the old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an experiment I would conduct.

Add a button to your Xaml and on click use `OpenFileDialog` to get a `FileInfo`.  From that `FileInfo` use its `Open` method to get a stream and pass that to `docViewer.LoadDocument`.

Now run it, click the button and select the same PDF document you are trying to send from the server.

If that succeeds you need to continue investigating your server streaming strategy.  On the other hand if you still have the same problem, well it doesn't get more raw than that.  Try other PDF files and start investigating the PDF component.  Have you ever actually used it successfully, if so how does this current usage differ.

Comment: I tried a different test. What I did was what you suggested in a previous comment. I added a secondary API that returns a byte[] rather than an encoded string. This worked. So encoding the byte[] into a base64 string somehow corrupted it or messed with the formatting. Thx.

Comment: @ghost_mv , Can you please put here your code , I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you should get the stream pointer back to 0 ,so this should do the trick

```
byte[] image = null;
image = Convert.FromBase64String(stringFromServerCall);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image);
stream.Position = 0;
docViewer.LoadDocument(stream);
```

Comment: I tried both that, as well as stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); and it yielded the same result of the blank viewer...

Comment: you mentioned byte array size , what about the stream.Length ?

Comment: I don't have access to the server side's stream length because it's using File.ReadAllBytes(), not a FileStream that's exposed for me to set a breakpoint near.

Comment: I meant at the client side after the intialization of stream ,just to make sure the stream did got the data, I assume the LoadDocument() is working fine and you tested it already as well ?

Comment: Yes the stream is populated. It is not empty. And yes, testing "LoadDocument" with an application resource stream works fine. But in my context, I cannot use that route. I must use the Memory Stream.

Comment: @Musaab: After constructing a MemoryStream with a byte array the initial position will already be 0, nothing has been read from it yet.